# Interpretation of the Shapiro test

Tags: normal-distribution

I would like to see if there is a difference between my 2 groups : AEMO pere and AEMO mere. First I check if my data follow a normal distribution or not. For that I use the Shapiro test. the results show me that the "mere" population do not follow a normal distribution and that the "pere" one do. 
In consequence, I will have to use a non parametric test like wilcoxon to compare those two groups. Is my reasoning correct ?
Thank you !!

[image: results of the Shapiro test]

Comment: Doesn't the fact that you have decided one group is a sample of a normal distribution and the other is not already answer your question about "a difference"?  If not, then please explain what *kind* of difference you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to trust the Shapiro Wilk (SW) test then yes, your interpretation is correct. Various people have raised issues about SW and other tests of normality and whether we should use them this way.

Personally, I would look at plots to check normality and then I'd compare results of the t-test and the Wilcoxon to see how much the non-normality affected things.

Comment: thank you for this fast answer ! I did both the t-test and the wilcoxon and in both cases wa can not reject H0. How would you "look at plots" ? I know that there is the qplot function but I'm not sure I'll be able to read the plot properly..

Comment: To check normality you can look at a quantile normal plot.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by a difference. From what you've posted, it seems like you've already found that they're different. One has a normal distribution. The other doesn't. No further work is necessary to say that they are different. A number of tests exist to check for general distribution differences. A classic is the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

If, however, you are only interested in differences between means, then some further work is necessary. The standard way to check for differences in means is the two-sample t-test. As you've pointed out, that assumes normality. However, remember the central limit theorem! I like Ben's answer here: [confidence interval for population parameters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419647/confidence-interval-for-population-parameters/419651#419651). The gist is that you get a test statistic approximately distributed as $t$ if you have finite variance. Running some simulations and checking QQ plots, even a sample from $t_{2.1}$ seems to give a sampling distribution that deviates from normality. However, sampling from $t_{4.1}$ looks fine to me.

```
set.seed(1)    
x.bars <- rep(NA,1000)
for (i in 1:1000){
    dist <- rt(250,4.1) # also check out 4.1
    x.bars[i] <- mean(dist)
}
qqnorm(x.bars)
qqline(x.bars)
```

You may elect to do a Wilcoxon test, but simply failing a goodness-of-fit test when you have reason to suspect normality (especially if you have a fairly large sample size) is not much of a reason to shy away from t-testing. The central limit theorem is pretty awesome.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!